# scikit learn pipelines and `ColumnTransformer`

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am confused by the following `Pipeline` weirdness. Suppose I define a pipeline thus:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('transformer', ColumnTransformer([('sc', StandardScaler(), [0, 1])])), 
    ('model', LinearRegression())
])
```

now define a dataframe thus:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4))
```

Now, interestingly, `pipe.fit(df[[0, 1, 2]], df[3])` works fine. However,
`pipe.predict(df[[0, 1, 2]])` does not, while `pipe.predict(df[0, 1])` does. This seems wrong (pipelines are supposed to do their magic on both `fit` and `predict` steps). Am I missing something?

Comment: There might be some mess with parenthesis. First option `pipe.predict(df[[0, 1, 2])` does not work because a closing `]` is missing (`pipe.predict(df[[0, 1, 2]])` should indeed work); `pipe.predict(df[[0, 1]])` does not work instead as you trained the model with 3 features and you're trying to predict with 2 features only.

Comment: @amiola There is certainly a ty;o in the question, but  not where it comes from, and the question is based on empirical experience. I will edit it more extensively later.